# What is an effective Awk/Nawk pattern for extracting path/filenames from input?

Tags: regex, string, bash, awk

Input contains filenames (`/path/to/file`) scattered throughout.
I just want the `/path/to/xyz.xyz` (space or newline, but never '\ ' [a space in a file]).

The rule is:

- Starts with '/' - begin
- End at ' ' (but not '\ ') or '\n'
- Everything in between.

Only paths+basename attached. Not basenames.

Comment: Even after the edit I still don't understand what is asked... Do the answers work for you? If yes, mark one of them as accepted. If not, comment under the answers the difference between the expected and the observed output.

Answer (score 2):

The following

```
{
  r = 0;
  s = $0;
  do
  {
    r = match(s, /\/([^ ]|\\ )+/ );
    if ( r > 0 )
    {
      print substr(s, RSTART, RLENGTH);
      s = substr(s, RSTART + RLENGTH);
    }
  }
  while ( r > 0 );
}
```

maybe is what you wanted. (Note: the path "/" is not caught because of the +, if you use `*` instead, it will be caught).

Answer (score 0):

You could rely on `awk` to do the splitting so that file names do not contain spaces, and then simply look for any field that starts with a `/`:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if (substr($i, 1, 1) == "/") print $i }'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ txr -c '@(freeform)
@(coll)@{path /\/[^ \n]*/}@(end)' -
asfasdf /foo/bar asdfasdf/xyzzy.gif /blah
/usr/local/bin .2466 /etc
[Ctr-D][Enter]
path[0]="/foo/bar"
path[1]="/xyzzy.gif"
path[2]="/blah"
path[3]="/usr/local/bin"
path[4]="/etc"
```

This dumps the raw bindings which allows the whole command to be`eval`-ed in Bash to create an array. (No requirement was given on the output format.)